# link a folder in a subst Drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I have following situation:

- I substed my D\ Drive to X\

What I want:

-I have a folder in X : **X:\test**
 Now I want to have a link in X: with folowing constelation:
  **X:\folder\test**

I tried following in a batchfile:

```
mkdir  X:\folder
mklink /D  X:\folder\test X:\test
```

Result:

If I run it normal: something like : **You don't have enough permission to do that**

as Admin:           something like : The System can't find the Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin command is running in a different context than the non admin, and it does not see the substed drive. Repeat the subst command in the admin command line and then create the link from it.